# How to find out what is missing in the Celery setup?

Tags: django, redis, celery

For one of our Django websites we need to have Celery running.

We use the following settings for Celery in the `settings.py`:

```
BROKER_URL = "redis://<ip address of the server>:6379/0"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis"
CELERY_REDIS_HOST = "<ip address of the server>"
CELERY_REDIS_PORT = 6379
CELERY_REDIS_DB = 0
```

Redis is running correctly:

```
$ redis-cli ping
PONG
```

We start the Celery server with this command:

```
$ nohup python manage.py celeryd start
```

Also we have a test app with a Celery task, however when we try to use it, the result is never given and the task hangs:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from celerytest.tasks import add
>>> result = add.delay(2, 2)
>>> result.ready() # returns True if the task has finished processing.
False
>>> result.result
None
>>> result.get()
```

We are using Django 1.3.7, Celery 3.0.9 and djcelery 3.0.9.

How can we find what is causing the hanging of Celery task?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to run the celeryd command with the -EB options. You can also run it on the foreground to ensure all is fine before sending it to the background.

e.g.

```
python manage.py celeryd -EB -l debug
```

I think for logging you should use something like below to instantiate your logger :

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

log = get_task_logger(__name__)
```

In your settings, you probably need to check this setting as well:

```
CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False
```

That way I think you should be able to see the logs.

Comment: Those options list out the available Celery tasks, but the tasks still cannot be run successfully in my case and there are no logs of any kind.